# How to upgrade to Thunderbird 60.3.3?

Tags: thunderbird

I have a bunch of bugs with the release of Thunderbird 60.2.1. I'd like to upgrade to Thunderbird 60.3.3 but I couldn't find it yet on https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa.

Do you know how I can upgrade using the Debian package system?

Comment: You don't say what problems you're having with TB. Maybe there are solutions. Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: My main issue is that the unified inbox is blank, sometime it shows emails but when I get over them with my mouse they desappear.

Comment: Do you use message filters that move messages to other folders?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: I dropped my profile and started fresh and everything looks to be working. I have no idea how I broke it and removing the smart folders didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download directly from Mozilla.

[Thunderbird 32bit](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/60.3.3/linux-i686/en-US/thunderbird-60.3.3.tar.bz2)

[Thunderbird 64bit](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/60.3.3/linux-x86_64/en-US/thunderbird-60.3.3.tar.bz2)

Once downloaded extract the files to `~/.thunderbird/(Profile name)/`

to clarify:

```
/home/user_name/.thunderbird/(Profile name)/
```

Or

Open Terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will install 60.4.0

Comment: I'd caution the user that the first method that you outline won't be a supported solution, and won't get updates... and I'd recommend backing up the profile folder first.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. :)